# HighChart and spline: dataGrouping not working

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, grouping

I have a chart of type `spline`, that shows a discrete curve.

Some of datapoints of this chart are very far each other, some other are very close.

I would like to use dataGrouping options to group automatically the points that are very close.

The objective is to aggregate the close points (for example I would like to show the average per week, now the points are per day) so they do not appear too close each other.

So I setted dataGrouping up in this way

```
    plotOptions: {
                                spline: {
                                    dataGrouping: {
                                        approximation: 'average',
                                        forced:false,
                                        units: [
                                            ['week', [1]]
                                        ],
                                        enabled: true

                                    },
                                },
                                ...
}
```

but it does not work.

What is wrong in this setting?

Answer (score 0):

The datagrouping doesnt reconigse if some points are close or not. The idea of working is group points per units, like "create single point based on 5". You can try also to use [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) parameter with false value.

Answer (score 0):

I found that dataGrouping is appliable only to HighStock charts.

I was using highcharts instead of highstock.

Changed to highstock, no it works